# How to suppress warnings for the flutter run command?

Tags: flutter, command-line-interface, warnings

I'm running `flutter run` on the command line for a new client and there are a bunch of warnings. Sometimes there's an error and it's hard to find in all the warnings. Is there a way to hide the warnings?

Example warnings:

```
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/drag_and_drop_lists-0.3.2+2/lib/measure_size.dart:23:22: Warning: Operand of null-aware
operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').    
    SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(postFrameCallback);
                     ^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/drag_and_drop_lists-0.3.2+2/lib/programmatic_expansion_tile.dart:139:22: Warning: Operand of    
null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
 - 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').    
    SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((Duration duration) {
                     ^
```

Comment: are you using vscode or android studio

Comment: I am using vscode.

Comment: Can you include an image/snippet of warning message

Comment: I included snippet in post.

Comment: You need to update your project & packages on flutter 3

Comment: What exactly do I need to update?

Comment: Packages on `pubspec.yaml`, this error comes because on flutter v3 instance isnot nullable

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, option is not currently available from what I know

Answer (score 0):

Set:

```
analyzer:

    warnings:

        todo: ignore
```

in your pubspec.yaml